Why is there a tick next to the “0 answers” of a question?
I just noticed that there was a tick next to the "0 answers" of a question when I’m searching it in this site.
See the screenshot below for the question:



I’ve never seen that case before, is this a bug? If this is not a bug, what does that mean?

This is a bug in the search process, which should check if the accepted answer is deleted, and in such case ignore it and don't consider it as accepted. It already knows to not count it, but for some reason (bug) considers it accepted.

This has already been answered on SO Meta.

The explanation for this is that there was an accepted answer that was later deleted:

This MSO post (provided by fyrepenguin) also seems to confirm the above explanation.

Is this a bug, or a feature, what do you think?

I don't know honestly, but if I had to guess it is not a feature@user1556492

@user1556492 see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431149/what-is-the-tick-next-to-the-0-answers

@user1556492 It's an edge case the system fails to account for. What's supposed to happen is that when an accepted answer is deleted, the accept vote is supposed to be removed (see also). In rare cases, as well as in early 2011 and earlier (i.e., before that feature was implemented), the accept vote is/was not removed. Basically, the system fails to account for that edge case in many cases.

Yes there is indeed an accepted answer by sock account of  the developer who handled the request. (Marc Gravell) (and it was deleted before the system started to remove the accept votes)
